# maven-eclipse-plugin with maven 3.8

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

After migration to jdk11 and maven 3.8.6 , is the plugin maven-eclipse-plugin still useful, knowing that it is noted that it is retired https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/
Should i delete this plugin from my pom.xml?

> org.apache.maven.plugins
>               maven-eclipse-plugin

how can i replace it?

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about, so no.

Comment: That plugin is retired since 2015... You could import a Maven project in Eclipse without supplemental plugin in Maven... but you should use a recent version of Eclipse... and simply there is no replacement in Maven for this...because the IDE handles that on its own.